# lsof compares to pfiles, difference?

Tags: solaris, lsof

pfiles in Solaris suspends files for a short period while examining them, however, lsof does not. How does lsof work that allows it to retrieve information while not suspending files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `lsof` read the kernel volatile memory, while `pfiles` directly read directly from the application interface, thus causing it to suspend for a short period of time.

For that reason, `lsof` does not truly provide an accurate system picture of the system, but it's better then the option of freezing the process while inspecting it.